# menu method in java

Tags: java, methods

I want to print menu by instructions method but program executes nothing. Can anyone advise me how I can fix this.

**Here is method declaration in class..**

```
public class Factorial 
{

    public void instructions()
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter your choice:\n",
        " 1 to calculate a factorial value of an integer.\n",
        " 2 to calculate mathematical constant e.\n",
        " 3 to calculate e^x.\n",
        " 4 to end.\n");        
    }  // End of instructions
}
```

**and here is the main that calls instruction method from Factorial class.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;    // Program uses scanner. 

public class behzat
{ 

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Factorial myfactorial = new Factorial();
        myfactorial.instructions();  

    }    

}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but `factorial` should be `Factorial`. Probably it's the sign of the end of the world if your code compiled the way it is now.

Comment: whats the problem , create a factorial object , call instructions method , whenever you want to print the instructions menu

Comment: Does your code compile? your class is `F`actorial  not `f`actorial.

Comment: it does not print the menu. The programs goes on after myfactorial.instructions();

Comment: @Behzat Are you sure you're writing `Factorial`? with `F` and not `f`?

Comment: Where/how do you run the program ?

Comment: Yes, I amended as Factorial but the program only prints " Enter your choice:" part. It does not print the rest of the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using printf, for which the first argument is actually a format string, that will print the *next* arguments according to that format.

So, even ignoring the class name error between factorial and Factorial, your code should only print `"Enter your choice:\n"`.

You need to use print instead:

```
System.out.print("Enter your choice:\n" +
    " 1 to calculate a factorial value of an integer.\n" +
    " 2 to calculate mathematical constant e.\n" +
    " 3 to calculate e^x.\n" +
    " 4 to end.\n");
```

Note that there is only one argument for this function, here separated by using string concatenation for easier reading.

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice the printf either hah.

Answer (score 3):

Class definitions begin with a capital letter. Try:

```
Factorial myfactorial = new Factorial();
myfactorial.instructions();
```

Comment: Thanks.I also amended  but  it prints only" Enter your choice:"  It does not print menu numbers..

Comment: You are using printf wrong. In this case it looks like you should just use println or print

Comment: @SirDarius posted a correct usage of print for your case. Note the '+' to attach the strings together.

Comment: I have just used println and print;  the compiler warns me that it is not applicable for the arguments.

Comment: sorry, where is your answer.. I am new at this site, sorry..  :(

Comment: Now I have seen.. Thank you so much.. :)